Using Polars, how do I do efficiently do an `over` that collects items into a list?
As a simple example, consider the following, using groupby:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    [pl.Series("id", ["a", "b", "a"]), pl.Series("x", [0, 1, 2])]
)
print(df.group_by("id").agg(pl.col("x")))

# shape: (2, 2)
# ┌─────┬───────────┐
# │ id  ┆ x         │
# │ --- ┆ ---       │
# │ str ┆ list[i64] │
# ╞═════╪═══════════╡
# │ b   ┆ [1]       │
# │ a   ┆ [0, 2]    │
# └─────┴───────────┘

But if we use over, we get:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    [pl.Series("id", ["a", "b", "a"]), pl.Series("x", [0, 1, 2])]
)
print(df.with_columns(pl.col("x").over("id")))
# shape: (3, 2)
# ┌─────┬─────┐
# │ id  ┆ x   │
# │ --- ┆ --- │
# │ str ┆ i64 │
# ╞═════╪═════╡
# │ a   ┆ 0   │
# │ b   ┆ 1   │
# │ a   ┆ 2   │
# └─────┴─────┘

How can the groupby result be achieved using over? Well, using mapping_strategy="join".
A slightly more complicated example, meant to showcase why we might want to use over instead of groupby:
import polars as pl

# the smallest value a Float32 can encode is 1e-38
# therefore, as far as we are concerned,
# 1e-41 and 1e-42 should be indistinguishable
# in other words, we do not want to use "other" as an id column
# but we do want to preserve other!
df = pl.DataFrame(
    [
        pl.Series("id", ["a", "b", "a"]),
        pl.Series("other", [1e-41, 1e-16, 1e-42], dtype=pl.Float32()),
        pl.Series("x", [0, 1, 2]),
    ]
)
print(df.group_by("id").agg(pl.col("x"), pl.col("other")).explode("other"))

# shape: (3, 3)
# ┌─────┬───────────┬────────────┐
# │ id  ┆ x         ┆ other      │
# │ --- ┆ ---       ┆ ---        │
# │ str ┆ list[i64] ┆ f32        │
# ╞═════╪═══════════╪════════════╡
# │ a   ┆ [0, 2]    ┆ 9.9997e-42 │
# │ a   ┆ [0, 2]    ┆ 1.0005e-42 │
# │ b   ┆ [1]       ┆ 1.0000e-16 │
# └─────┴───────────┴────────────┘

Now, using over:
import polars as pl

# the smallest value a Float32 can encode is 1e-38
# therefore, as far as we are concerned,
# 1e-41 and 1e-42 should be indistinguishable
# in other words, we do not want to use "other" as an id column
# but we do want to preserve other!
df = pl.DataFrame(
    [
        pl.Series("id", ["a", "b", "a"]),
        pl.Series("other", [1e-41, 1e-16, 1e-42], dtype=pl.Float32()),
        pl.Series("x", [0, 1, 2]),
    ]
)
print(df.with_columns(pl.col("x").over(["id"], mapping_strategy="join")))

# shape: (3, 3)
# ┌─────┬────────────┬───────────┐
# │ id  ┆ other      ┆ x         │
# │ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---       │
# │ str ┆ f32        ┆ list[i64] │
# ╞═════╪════════════╪═══════════╡
# │ a   ┆ 9.9997e-42 ┆ [0, 2]    │
# │ b   ┆ 1.0000e-16 ┆ [1]       │
# │ a   ┆ 1.0005e-42 ┆ [0, 2]    │
# └─────┴────────────┴───────────┘

The trouble using mapping_strategy="join" is that its very slow. So, this suggests that I ought to do a group_by followed by a join:
import polars as pl
import polars.selectors as cs

# the smallest value a Float32 can encode is 1e-38
# therefore, as far as we are concerned,
# 1e-41 and 1e-42 should be indistinguishable
# in other words, we do not want to use "other" as an id column
# but we do want to preserve other!
df = pl.DataFrame(
    [
        pl.Series("id", ["a", "b", "a"]),
        pl.Series("other", [1e-41, 1e-16, 1e-42], dtype=pl.Float32()),
        pl.Series("x", [0, 1, 2]),
    ]
)


print(
    df.select(cs.exclude("x")).join(
        df.group_by("id").agg("x"),
        on="id",
        # we expect there to be multiple "id"s on the left, matching
        # a single "id" on the right
        validate="m:1",
    )
)

# shape: (3, 3)
# ┌─────┬────────────┬───────────┐
# │ id  ┆ other      ┆ x         │
# │ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---       │
# │ str ┆ f32        ┆ list[i64] │
# ╞═════╪════════════╪═══════════╡
# │ a   ┆ 9.9997e-42 ┆ [0, 2]    │
# │ b   ┆ 1.0000e-16 ┆ [1]       │
# │ a   ┆ 1.0005e-42 ┆ [0, 2]    │
# └─────┴────────────┴───────────┘

But perhaps I am missing something else about over?

I'd expect pl.col.x.implode().over("id") to work but it doesn't. Apparently, that's expected - https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9780

@RomanPekar is pl.col.x instead of pl.col("x") something that actually works?!

Oh wow, it does work. It actually does work.

Currently, Polars does not distinguish between Scalars and Series. Any Series with length 1 is considered a scalar and will be broadcasted when combined with other series.
We are actively working on distinguishing these two concepts better, and once we have done so I would expect list aggregations like Expr.implode() in over contexts to work as you'd expect. That is, the following should solve your problem, but currently doesn't:
>>> df.with_columns(pl.col.x.implode().over("id")))

To do it currently I would suggest a normal aggregation + join:
>>> df.drop("x").join(df.group_by("id").agg("x"), on="id")
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬────────────┬───────────┐
│ id  ┆ other      ┆ x         │
│ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---       │
│ str ┆ f32        ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════╪════════════╪═══════════╡
│ a   ┆ 9.9997e-42 ┆ [0, 2]    │
│ b   ┆ 1.0000e-16 ┆ [1]       │
│ a   ┆ 1.0005e-42 ┆ [0, 2]    │
└─────┴────────────┴───────────┘

